# Checking for positive or negative number

Tags: jquery, livevalidation

How can we check if the input number is either positive or negative in LiveValidation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

easier way is to multiply the contents with 1 and then compare with 0 for +ve or -ve

```
try{
   var n=$("#...").val() * 1;
   if(n>=0){
        //...Do stuff for +ve num
   }else{
       ///...Do stuff -ve num
   }       
}catch(e){
  //......
}
```

REGEX:

```
 var n=$("#...").val()*1;
 if (n.match(new RegExp(^\d*\.{0,1}\d*$))) {
   // +ve numbers (with decimal point like 2.3)
 } else if(n.match(new RegExp(^-\d*\.{0,1}\d*$))){
   // -ve numbers (with decimal point like -5.34)
 }
```

Comment: regular expression for checking positive number

Answer (score 4):

```
try
{
    if ((new Number( $('#numberInput').val()) < 0)
    {
        // Number is negative
    }
    else
    {
        // Otherwise positive
    }
} catch ( error)
{
    alert( "Not a number!");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use JavaScript's method eg:

```
var pos_value = Math.abs(n_val);
```

Thanks
Dev

Comment: The question is finding negative number, not converting to positive numner.